# reduce tab switching delay

Tags: react-native, native-base

Actual behavior - takes time to switch between tabs

Expected behavior - switching without time delay

**code:**

```
<Tabs initialPage={0} tabBarUnderlineStyle={'black'}>
       <Tab heading="send">
       <Send/>
       </Tab>
       <Tab heading="request">
       <Request/>
       </Tab>
       <Tab heading="add">
       <Add/>
       </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

**scenario:**

After clicking add tab it takes a specific amount of time to switch, but  I want to switch without any time delay 
official documentation has no such property mentioned here is the link https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-advanced-headref

version details - 
    "native-base": "^2.2.1"
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    "react-native": "0.46.3"